# MVVM Get Control Position

Tags: wpf, canvas, mvvm

I am a bit stuck in my current project.

I'm using a terrible API that needs to be told where and when to draw at any give time. This API does not expose any controls, and I need a control in order to place the drawn object properly.

What I have done is I've put a canvas in my grid in my view. This canvas takes up the space that my drawn API element needs to take up. So, by getting the canvas actualwidth and actualheight, I can draw my API element at the proper size. The issue i'm having is the position of the API element. The Canvas is in the proper place at all times, but when the program first starts, Canvas.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), App.Current.MainWindow); returns 0,0. As soon as I manipulate the UI and cause the Canvas to Resize, the location function returns the real location and my API element draws in the proper spot. My question is why is the initial location 0? How can I remedy this? I call the initial draw function from the UserControl_Loaded event.

Thanks

P.S. Would I be wrong in thinking that the initial 0,0 is a relative coordinate, and not an absolute coordinate?

Comment: I'm using this function to get the location:
`System.Windows.Point location = WaveformCanvas.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), App.Current.MainWindow);`

However, this function claims that the two elements do not share a common ancestor:
`location = WaveformCanvas.TransformToVisual(App.Current.MainWindow).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));`

But after the first call to this function, the two do share a common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue - my control wasn't part of the PresentationSource. Long story short, you can't get the location of a control that isn't shown on the screen yet. My fix was this:
`private void WaveformCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        if((sender as Canvas).IsVisible)
        {
            (this.DataContext as StudioControlViewModel).MoveWaveform();
        }
 }`

For me, the `MoveWaveform()` function calls `WaveformCanvas.TranslatePoint(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), App.Current.MainWindow);`

So now the function only gets called when the control is visible, which has solved all of my issues.